# Mysql error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint[ foreign keys same type, innodb ]

Tags: mysql, sql, types

I need a fresh pair of eyes to see what exactly I am doing wrong here.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `spring_normalize`.`users` (
  `username` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(80) NULL,
  `authority` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `enabled` TINYINT(1) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(60) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`username`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `spring_normalize`.`offers` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `users_username` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `users_username`),
INDEX `fk_offers_users_idx` (`users_username` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `fk_offers_users`
  FOREIGN KEY (`users_username`)
  REFERENCES `spring_normalize`.`users` (`username`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

From other people who has the same problem:

1. Is Db InnoDB? Yes
2. Are all tables InnoDB ? Yes
3. Is unique index present on referencing table ? Yes
4. Are referenced and referencing column exactly of the same type ? Yes

Question what do am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Can't repeat](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2f001), also tried locally with a `spring_normalize` database created and full database name. Are you sure neither of the tables exist in a previous - different - form, since you only create if not exists?

Comment: Your code -- minus the database names -- works fine on SQL Fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d2f00.

Comment: The problem is not reproducible, you got something wrong. It is working on MariaDB 10, too. The error is from a different script.

Comment: Your code is working fine.. but i think there was a problem in database name.. as i have faced same issue when i had used diff database name at a time of foreign key creation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff database name can't have underscore?

Comment: Please include the error message exactly as you get it. Also lacks a [mcve] as the comments stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the others stated in comments, your queries are correct

Couple of things you can try :

---

Select your database first and remove it from your 2 `create table`

```
USE `spring_normalize`;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `username` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(80) NULL,
  `authority` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `enabled` TINYINT(1) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(60) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`username`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `offers` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `users_username` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `users_username`),
INDEX `fk_offers_users_idx` (`users_username` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `fk_offers_users`
  FOREIGN KEY (`users_username`)
  REFERENCES `users` (`username`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

---

Try to specify this before the create tables in case the engine would (weirdly) try to create the table `offers` before `users`:

```
-- Do not check foreign key constraints
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

---

and finally if nothing solves it, do this after having received the error, it will give you more info

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
```